# Casting to a recursively bounded type

Tags: java, generics, casting

I defined a Java interface to represent the ability of an object to copy itself (no, I don't want to use `Cloneable`, but thanks for the suggestion ;-). It's generic:

```
public interface Copiable<T> {
    T copy();
}
```

An object will only make copies of its own type:

```
public class Foo implements Copiable<Foo> {
    Foo copy() { return new Foo(); }
}
```

Now, I'm reading `Class<?>` objects from a non-generic API (Hibernate metadata, if that is of interest to anyone), and, if they are `Copiable`, I want to register them with one of my components. The `register` method has the following signature:

```
<T extends Copiable<T>> register(Class<T> clazz);
```

My problem is, how do I cast the class before passing it to the method? What I'm currently doing is:

```
Class<?> candidateClass = ...
if (Copiable.class.isAssignableFrom(candidateClass)) {
    register(candidateClass.asSubclass(Copiable.class));
}
```

This does what I want, but with a compiler warning. And I don't think I'll be able to express the recursive bound in a runtime cast.

Is there a way to rework my code to make it typesafe?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A runtime cast to `<? extends Copiable<?>` fails (in the `register()` call) because there's no way to declare that the first `?` and the second `?` are the same (unknown) thing.

The `asSubclass()` call gives you a compiler warning for pretty much the same reason -- because the generics have been erased, there's no way at runtime to prove that a `Copiable` is a `Copiable<AnythingInParticular>`. You've proved that it's a `Copiable`, but you haven't proved that it's a `Copiable<Itself>`.

I think the best you can hope for is to localize the warnings to one messy method, and add  `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")` and some comments.

Do you know for sure this will work at runtime? I get the feeling the compiler's telling the truth here. Do the classes you're getting from Hibernate actually extend `Copiable`, or do they just happen to declare methods that match the `Copiable` interface? If it's the latter, then -- Java being a strongly typed language -- your `isAssignableFrom()` is always going to return false anyway.

Comment: Yes, this confirms what I intuited. Then I'll assume that if a class implements Copiable, it implements Copiable<Itself>, and I can safely ignore the warning. This is acceptable since all the classes are under my control. I accept this answer, thanks!

Comment: And yes, that works at runtime. The classes I'm getting from Hibernate are the classes of my entities, where I declare the interface.

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to cast non-generic API to generic and not get a warning. You can use `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")` annotation to suppress it.
`Class<?>` is rather pointless in this case, too - you can use non-generic `Class candidateClass` instead.

Comment: Actually, there is a way: if the type parameter of my method was non-recursive, e.g <T extends SomeInterface>, candidateClass.asSubclass(SomeInterface.class) would give me the correct type. Surely, asSubclass can throw a ClassCastException at runtime, but that would never happen as I test the type with isAssignableFrom => no warning.
My question is whether I can do that with a recursive type parameter.

Comment: Btw, Class<?> is not pointless: if I used Class I'd get another warning for using a raw type.

Comment: That's not what I meant. You've said in your question that you're obtaining   `candidateClass` from non-generic API. Or did I misinterpret that? If it is indeed non-generic then **by definition** there's no way to convert it to generic without a warning. As far as what I meant by "pointless", `Class<?>` has the same semantic  meaning as non-generic `Class` and if you're going to be suppressing the warning anyway you just might use the latter.

Comment: The warning is not on the first line of the last snippet. It's on the third line. Again, the issue was not about obtaining the class from a non-generic API: if I didn't have the recursive bound, I could write the code in a completely type-safe way, without suppressing any warning.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could apply the [super type token](http://gafter.blogspot.com/2006/12/super-type-tokens.html) paradigm somehow? Why do you need to constrain your register()? I think the problem is that you use Class.forName and it is too much a runtime thing.

Comment: Nice link indeed, but I don't think it will solve my problem. I constrain register, well, to express a constraint on the type of classes that will be accepted :-) Granted, I will probably end up suppressing a warning, but in the client code. I mean, if I write a call to register with a class literal, it provide the correct type safety. The problem is that my client doesn't know the class until runtime.